# hp -ux remote cpio copy

Tags: unix

```
REMOTE SERVER
remsh remoteserverhostname -l remoteusername find /tmp/a1/ | cpio -o > /tmp/paketr.cpio

LOCAL SERVER
rcp remoteserverhostname:/tmp/paketr.cpio /tmp/aaa
cpio -idmv < /tmp/paketr.cpio
```

I'm trying to get and create directory structure from remote server to local server. I can do this with following command list
but I wonder if I can do this with just one command

by running cpio with pass-through mode

```
remsh remoteserverhostname find /tmp/a1 | cpio -pd /tmp

current </tmp/tmp/a1/b1/y1> newer
current </tmp/tmp/a1/b1/z1> newer
current </tmp/tmp/a1/b2/l2smc> newer
"/tmp/a1/b3": No such file or directory
Cannot stat </tmp/a1/b3>.
0 blocks
```

So when I try to `cpio -pd option` , I'm expecting it to create directories for me but it does not.

I was using `rcp` but its not preserving symbolic links :(

What can I do ?
hp-ux

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to copy just the directory structure (i.e. directories only), or the files too? If copying everything, try:

```
ssh remoteserverhostname 'find /tmp/a1 | cpio -o' | cpio -idmv
```

If just the directories, then use:

```
ssh remoteserverhostname 'find /tmp/a1 -type d | cpio -o' | cpio -idmv
```

(I recommend `ssh` rather than `remsh`, as it's way more secure, but the same commands ought to work with `remsh` too...)

Comment: i need to preserve owner of file any comment ?

Comment: and what about zipping file while transfer and reopen it on local machine

Comment: For compression - if using `ssh` just add the `-C` option before the server name. For preserving the owner - `cpio` should do this automatically, but can only do so if running as root.

Comment: is there any option for preserve owner for other users if i want to use this command with other non root user what can i do ? i am using remsh so C option is available for it ?

Comment: No - normal users can't create files owned by other users (it's part of the Unix security model). I really strongly advise using `ssh` rather than `remsh`; `remsh` has huge security issues. If you must use it with compression, try adding `| gzip -` after `cpio -o`, and `gunzip - |` before `cpio -idmv`. (Use `bzip2`/`bunzip2` if they're installed on your system for better compression.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).